# Can't access jaspersever login page. The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource

Tags: tomcat, jasperserver

I installed commercial verison of JasperReports Server in bundle with Tomcat and PostgreSQL. After installation completed I can't access to jasperserver login page. I kept default port config of tomcat, so it's port 8080 and tomcat page on localhost:8080 works properly. But when I'm tring to open localhost:8080/jasperserver-pro i get:

`HTTP Status 404 – Not Found`
`Type: Status Report`
`Message: The requested resource [/jasperserver-pro] is not available`
`Description: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.`

I tried to change port in **server.xml** in **Connector** tag and it didn't help. Please help.

Edit, I added logs from tomcat:

https://pastebin.com/nm4b112k
https://pastebin.com/TzuqRznQ

Comment: Have a look in the tomcat logs, maybe it's failing to load jasperserver for some reason.

Comment: I added them above. There are some errors but I don't know what they mean

Comment: It can't find the keystore files. See this: https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/encryption-jasperreports-server-75

Comment: I tried to update and move to different directory those keystore files as it is written but still it dosen't work. I have a suspicion it doesn't work out of the box because of a space in my user's home directory name. Tomorrow I will try to install this on another user.

Comment: Ok, i tried again to move keystore files to different folder and now in logs I'm getting `Current system user is unable to access the 'C:\keys\.jrsksp'`, but I gave all permissions to user I use. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to put the keystore in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-x.y.z. And update the keystore.init.properties file.

Comment: I don't have Apache Software Foundation directory. I installed JasperReports server in bundle with tomcat, so i have this path `C:\Jaspersoft\jasperreports-server-8.0.0\apache-tomcat`. I put there keystore and still getting log `Current system user is unable to access the 'C:\Jaspersoft\jasperreports-server-8.0.0\apache-tomcat'`.

Comment: See the windows section: https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/keystore-management-and-repair#Instructions_for_7.8